# How to read the o/p of the 'git log' command?

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have cloned a Git repository and would like to visualize the different branches and merges. I ran the following command.

```
git log --graph --full-history --all --color \
        --pretty=format:"%x1b[31m%h%x09%x1b[32m%d%x1b[0m%x20%s"
```

to get the following output

[image]

and this

[image]

How do I read this? What is the significance of `*` `/` `\` and `|`? Also, is there any way to filter out the only the branching and merging from the `git log` command by removing the code commits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Star must show you branch, to which commit belongs (it multibranch tree)

| / \ is just an attempt to draw DAG (see d7382a7 + b5b217d together f.e)

For merge-only commits all is bad, you can try

- --grep=pattern

> Limit the commits output to ones with log message that matches the
>   specified pattern (regular expression).

or get full log, log **without merges** (`--no-merges`) and subtract somehow 2-nd from first